# Conditionally bind an event in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Is it possible to conditionally bind an event using `.trigger()` or `.delegate()` in the html view?

This is the regular way:

`<div mousedown.delegate="handleMouseDown($event)"></div>`

I was thinking of something like:

`<div mousedown.delegate="isDraggable ? handleMouseDown($event) : null"></div>`

Ideally if `isDraggable === false` no handler is registered.

Currently I'm just doing this check in the view model `attached()` function with `.addEventListener()` is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried? It works fine for me.

Comment: @thebluefox I have now and yes it does work, I was looking at the docs and didn't see it mentioned anywhere so I just (foolishly) assumed only functions were allowed.

Comment: Yeah it's not mentioned in the docs. Aurelia is an excellent framework but the docs don't do it justice in places.

Comment: Not sure about the etiquette should I delete this question?

Comment: You can just self answer with your working code - then mark your answer as accepted :)

Comment: Actually - I'll vote to close this instead as that's probably the right thing.

Comment: @thebluefox there isnt really any grounds to close this; it's on topic and a well formulated question. Should just answer it

Comment: @8protons well I presumed on the grounds that it's was easily resolved (as it simply worked anyway). Though I can see the benefit of it given the official documentation is lacking in not covering this specific area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @thebluefox pointed out in the question comments

`<div mousedown.delegate="isDraggable ? handleMouseDown($event) : null"></div>`

does work however there are some issues when adding in a binding behavior.

The following examples will fail when evaluating the ternary

`<div mousedown.delegate="isDraggable ? handleMouseDown($event) & throttle:500 : null"></div>`

`<div mousedown.delegate="isDraggable ? (handleMouseDown($event) & throttle:500) : null"></div>`

As a workaround you can invert the test so the binding is last e.g.

`<div mousemove.delegate="!isDraggable ? null : handleMouseMove($event) & throttle:500 "></div>`